# How to increment a variable with time() in the backend

Tags: php, time

I have an Ajax function which is returning me a value from the backend every second.

If I echo time() in the backend, the value would steadily change on my page.

What I want is a value of 10 for example, which I am preparing in the backend that increases every second by 1.

I thought I could use the time() function for that.

For example

```
$var = (10 + time()) -time();
```

The time functions, however, are counting against each other, means I can't see the value being changed obviously.
Is there a brilliant formula which would allow me to use time() to count up my $var? This is probably a simple math problem.

If there is any other easier way please tell me.

I know I could do it with javascript in the frontend, but before the value reaches the frontend I am converting the value to a date() string.
So it might be easier to do that beforehand.

Basically, all I need is for example 45:15:23 (hours, minutes, seconds) to count up seconds.

Comment: you're using server-side to count seconds? PHP is HTTP-request based.. how do you expect this to work? Client-side problems require client-side solutions

Comment: each second, com'on, you cant overload your server with each second request, soon you will run into backlog problem, please use some javascript code for counters and timing

Comment: I already have such a thing: $var = 10 + time(). works flawlessly

Comment: It's pointless to do that with JavaScript. Because if the value changes in my database, I need that value on my page

Comment: @zunae why would it change in your DB, and if it does, just get JS to count from that?

Comment: @treyBake it's an estimated delivery time that constantly changes. But if done with JS, after a page reload the value will reset, doesn't it?

Comment: @zunae why would an ETA constantly change? It should only change per stage of a process - not as a constant changing value.

Comment: from a logics point of view I'd rather go with an ajax endpoint that delivers the ETA, something like `GET:/eta?id=10`. Afterwards I'd use the resulting timestamp to do the date formatting with JavaScript.

Comment: It's not a package or an item you ordered. It's more a time of completion, and that does indeed change constantly. Because it's based on the current productions performance which is getting live data from the the CNC-Machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>(Type a title for your page here)</title>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function display_c(){
var refresh=1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
mytime=setTimeout('display_ct()',refresh)
}

function display_ct() {
var x = new Date();
document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x;
display_c();
 }
</script>
</head>

<body onload=display_ct();>
<span id='ct' ></span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: a good answer has an explanation (and indenting) to allow the OP and future visitors to learn from ti